# What is different between tf.group and tensorflow collection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm new in tensorflow

There are two ways we can run many tensor at once.
use `collection` and `tf.gruop`
but i'm not sure with two difference

For simple example

```
const0=tf.constant(8)
const1=tf.constant(11)

tf.add_to_collection('my_collection' , const0)
tf.add_to_collection('my_collection' , const1)

#or 
tf.group(const0 , const1)
```

The code below is `Mandelbrot fractal` implemented by tensorflow 
There was no difference btw the one executed using `tf.group` and `collection`

```
#step = tf.group(
#  tf.assign(zs, zs_add),
#  tf.assign_add(ns, zs_cast)
#)

#tf.add_to_collection('my_collection',tf.assign(zs, zs_add))
#tf.add_to_collection('my_collection',(ns, zs_cast))
#step = tf.get_collection('my_collection')
#

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Concept
# input initial value
#Y, X = np.mgrid[-1.3:1.3:0.005, -2:1:0.005]
Y, X = np.mgrid[-1.3:1.3:0.005, -2:1:0.005]

init_value = X + 1j*Y

#
xs = tf.constant(init_value )
zs = tf.Variable(xs)
zs_zeros = tf.zeros_like(xs, tf.float32)
ns = tf.Variable(zs_zeros)

zs_squre = tf.multiply(zs,zs)
zs_add = tf.add(zs_squre , xs)
zs_abs = tf.abs(zs_add)

zs_less = tf.math.less(zs_abs , 4)
zs_cast = tf.cast(zs_less , tf.float32)

#
step = tf.group(
  tf.assign(zs, zs_add),
  tf.assign_add(ns, zs_cast)
)


#
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(200):
    sess.run(step)
value = sess.run(ns)
plt.imshow(value)
plt.show()
```

SO THIS IS MY QUESTION 
what is difference with `tf.group` and `collection`?
thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tf.group` creates an operation **inside the computational graph** that once evaluated executes all the tensors in the group:

```
op = tf.group(a,b)
```

`tf.add_to_collection` instead, creates a group of operations **not** inside the computational graph, but only in the python script.

```
tf.add_to_collection('coll', a)
tf.add_to_collection('coll', b)
```

You can see this by looking at the description of `op` and `tf.get_collection('coll'):

- op: `<tf.Operation 'group_deps' type=NoOp>`
- tf.get_collection: `[<tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'Const_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>]`

In your example, using `tf.group` or `tf.add_to_collection` + `tf.get_collection` is the same: you just need all the operations executed in parallel, hence `sess.run(op)` and `sess.run(tf.get_collection('coll'))` have the same behaviour.

But in the case of the export of a computational graph (that's just an example to make you understand a possible scenario), you can't rely upon a python list, hence you have to use `tf.group`